# cmd parallel execution and termination

Tags: windows, bash, cmd

I have the following bash script:

```
node ./build.js & node ./server.js
```

It creates two nodejs processes and executes them in parallel. When I press `Ctrl-C`, both processes are terminated.

I'm trying to do the same with Windows cmd shell. Here's what I have currently:

```
start /B node ./build.js & node ./server.js
```

It successfully starts the same two processes, but after I press `Ctrl-C` it kills only the second one; the `node ./build.js` remains active and I have no easy way to terminate it from the console.

Sadly PowerShell is not an option here, because these scripts should run as part of npm scripts, and it could use only cmd as Windows shell.

Comment: Even if you can't run PowerShell commands directly from node, as long as you can run cmd commands, you can use powershell.exe to execute anything. In essence:

    powershell -Command "Get-Item ."

Comment: @aulme, thank you, that's a good idea. I could accept your answer if you provide a solution to reproduce this bash script with PowerShell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you can't run PowerShell commands directly from node, as long as you can run cmd commands, you can use powershell.exe to execute anything. In essence:

```
powershell -Command "Get-Item ."
```

Now, to the actual solution:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process -NoNewWindow node .\server1.js; Start-Process -NoNewWindow node .\server2.js"
```

The command above should launch both server1 and server2 and Ctrl+C or equivalent would terminate both child processes.

Comment: I had to modify this to `powershell -Command "Start-Process -NoNewWindow node ./build.js; Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait node ./server.js"` (note additional `-Wait`). Thank you, that's a good answer!

Answer (score 1):

A cross-platform solution (Win, Linux, Mac) to running multiple processes from an npm script is to install the parallelshell npm library.

```
npm install parallelshell --save-dev
```

Then in your `package.json` file you can have define the script as follows:

```
"scripts": {
  "myScript" : "parallelshell \"node ./build.js\" \"node ./server.js\""    
}
```

To execute `npm run myScript`.  Or even quicker - call the script `start` instead of `myScript` and execute `npm start`.

NB - Windows doesn't recognise single quotes hence the escaped double quotes in the script.